# Matrix Pivot Columns are Linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Prove that the $n^{\text{th}}$ column of a matrix is pivotal if and only if it is linearly independent of all previous columns $i, i < n.$

Note (definition): a column of a matrix is pivotal if the index is pivotal in the reduced row echelon
form of the matrix.

To prove the $\implies$ direction, since we know the column can be pivotal only if its index is pivotal which means it is the first column with a nonzero in a new row in the reduced row form, the column has to be independent from previous columns. To prove the other direction, if column $n$ is independent with previous columns, that means column $n$ has to be the new pivotal column according to the above note/definition.

Is this proof missing something? If not, is there a more elegant way of expressing this proof? (I feel like mine is wordy and not concise)

Comment: The first direction is good (and I think 1 sentence is as concise as it gets). But your direction basically says “follows from the definition” which isn’t really a complete argument.

Comment: I do not really know how to explain the other direction other than just using the definition, could you please explain how to make the argument more rigorous/full?